# Updating ngFor when Input value changes

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I'm trying to get an better understanding of Angular 2. I am receiving a list of people from endpoint and periodically the list changes. People Component:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'people-display',
   template: <ol class="people-list">
                <li *ngFor="let person of people">
                   <attendees [people]="peopleValue"></attendees>
                </li>
             </ol>
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnChanges {
   @Input() people: string[];
}
```

Attendees Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'attendees',
  templateUrl: '<span>{{attendees}}</span>',
})
export class AttendeesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I've looked for a way to change automatically update my template whenever the value of input changes.  I have yet to find a way of doing this.  I've thought about doing a setTimout, but there has to be more efficient way.  Can someone assist me or point me in the right direction? I need the ngFor to update dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

The question is how do you pass `people` to your component.

Assuming that your component is `my-people`  then you should pass `people` as following

```
<my-people [people]="peopleValue" .... ></my-people>
```

Comment: I have this and I'm receiving an error. The error states people isn't a known property of li `<li *ngFor="let person of people" [people]="peopleValue">{{person}}</li>`

Comment: The binding of `[people]="peopleValue" is not on the `<li>`. It goes where you are going to use custom component

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do anything manually inorder to track changes, angular2 framework automatically does that , make sure you pass the people as a input to your child component,

Assuming mycomponent is your child component and **`people`** is the input

```
<mycomponent [people]="peopleValue" .... ></mycomponent>
```

Comment: That looks familiar!

Comment: @AmrElAdawy yes i dint notice your answer, sorry

Comment: I have this and I'm receiving an error.  The error states people isn't a known property of li 

`<li *ngFor="let person of people" [people]="peopleValue">{{person}}</li>`

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose Angular provides you `two way binding` where any further changes to the model gets refelected to the template automatically and vice-versa.

Example:

**List Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-comp',
    template: `<ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let item of people">{{item}}</li>
               </ul>`
})

export class MyComp {
    @Input() people: string[];
}
```

**Usage**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'main-comp',
    template: '<my-comp [people]="list"></my-comp>'
})


export class MainComp {
    private list: string[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.list= ['male', 'female'];
    }
}
```

Comment: No don't do that. To reduce the code coupling and increase the modularity & code re usability, always split the code as much as possible.